# How can I refresh/update a cloned repository from Bitbucket. I cloned it from Azure Devops

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, bitbucket, azure-data-factory

I am currently working in Azure Data Factory and i'm using Azure DevOps as repository. Since our company uses Bitbucket, I cloned and linked the DevOps repository to Bitbucket and I have the same content in both repositories. If I make a change in the DevOps, it doesn't reflect on the Bitbucket repository. Is there a way to "refresh" the link in order to update the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Azure DevOps, you can set up a pipeline with the following steps for your Git repository:

1. **Checkout Bitbucket repository:** Execute the Bash script below.

```sh
git config --global user.email "<your user email>"
git config --global user.name "<your user name>"

find . -type f | grep -i "\.git" | xargs rm

cd ..
mkdir Bitbucket_repo
cd Bitbucket_repo
git clone https://<USERNAMR>:$(Bitbucket_App_password)@bitbucket.org/<Workspace_ID>/<Repo_Name>.git
```

The value of the secret variable **`$(Bitbucket_App_password)`** can be an [App password](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/app-passwords/) or [personal access token (PAT)](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/personal-access-tokens-939515499.html) for your Bitbucket account. The App password or PAT must has the **`Read & Write`** permissions to the Bitbucket repositories.

2. **Copy updated files to local Bitbucket repository:** Copy the updated files from local DevOps Git repository to the local Bitbucket Git repository using the [**Copy files task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

- *Source Folder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)*
- *Target Folder: $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/Bitbucket_repo/<Repo_Name>*

3. **Push updated files to remote Bitbucket repository:** Execute the Bash script below.

```sh
cd ../Bitbucket_repo/<Repo_Name>
git add -A
git commit -m "$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)"
git push
```

In this way, when you push new changes to your Git repository on Azure DevOps, the pipeline is triggered to execute the 3 steps to sync the new changes to the Bitbucket repository.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Factory only support Azure or Github as a git data source so you can't pull request back into the original one (if that is what you were planning).

What do you mean with 'linked'? Did you import the BT repo into Azure Devops?

I guess you could use plain old git commands inside the pipeline to keep them synced, but I don't see an use case in having these two repo's, perhaps you can clarify?

Comment: I know ADF only supports Azure or Github as repository, the idea is to use those two as a bridge in order to use Bitbucket as repository. What I did was I cloned the DevOps repo into Bitbucket with a Personal Access Token and linked it with the URL. So now I have the exact same repository in Bitbucket, but when I Publish something, the new material doesn't appear in the Bitbucket repo, only in DevOps repo

Comment: Yeah ADF doesn't magically syncs back to BT, as it is connected to your Azure Repo clone. You have to sync it in a pipeline or something.